# Create dataframe and set column as datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to create a pandas dataframe df like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "group": ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A"],
        "date": ["2020-01-02", "2020-01-13", "2020-02-01", "2020-02-23", "2020-03-05"],
        "value": [10, 20, 16, 31, 56],
    }
)
```

I want to specify column "date" as dtype=datetime64[ns] while creating the dataframe, not afterwards.

So not like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "group": ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A"],
        "date": ["2020-01-02", "2020-01-13", "2020-02-01", "2020-02-23", "2020-03-05"],
        "value": [10, 20, 16, 31, 56],
    }
)
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
```

But like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "group": ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A"],
        "date": pd.Series(
            ["2020-01-02", "2020-01-13", "2020-02-01", "2020-02-23", "2020-03-05"],
            dtype=np.datetime64,
        ),
        "value": [10, 20, 16, 31, 56],
    }
)
```

but that gives the error:

> ValueError: The 'datetime64' dtype has no unit. Please pass in 'datetime64[ns]' instead.

Doing that

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "group": ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A"],
        "date": pd.Series(
            ["2020-01-02", "2020-01-13", "2020-02-01", "2020-02-23", "2020-03-05"],
            dtype=np.datetime64[ns],
        ),
        "value": [10, 20, 16, 31, 56],
    }
)
```

I get this error:

> NameError: name 'ns' is not defined

So how can I set a specific column as type "datetime64[ns]"?

Comment: Change `np.datetime64` to `'datetime64[ns]'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) within the dict, as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "group": ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A"],
        "date": pd.to_datetime(["2020-01-02", "2020-01-13", "2020-02-01", "2020-02-23", "2020-03-05"]),
        "value": [10, 20, 16, 31, 56],
    }
)
```

`date` column is in `datetime64[ns]` format, as you can see by `df.info()`

```
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------  --------------  -----         
 0   group   5 non-null      object        
 1   date    5 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 2   value   5 non-null      int64         
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 248.0+ bytes
```

Comment: OP need `So how can I set a specific column as type "datetime64[ns]"?`

Comment: @jezrael  The created column is of dtype `datetime64[ns]` as can be seen from `df.info()`.  Isn't it anything I missing ?

Comment: @jezrael  My interpretation was that so long as the final result get the required dtype it will be fine, rather than we need a step to set the dtype **during the process**.  It is sometimes difficult to guess what OP wants.  Thanks for your reminder anyway.  Have a nice day   :-)

Comment: ya, I think to_datetime is best solution here, only OP need something else, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

Use `dtype='datetime64[ns]'`:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "group": ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A"],
        "date": pd.Series(
            ["2020-01-02", "2020-01-13", "2020-02-01", "2020-02-23", "2020-03-05"],
            dtype='datetime64[ns]',
        ),
        "value": [10, 20, 16, 31, 56],
    }
)
```

OR

use `astype()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "group": ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A"],
        "date": ["2020-01-02", "2020-01-13", "2020-02-01", "2020-02-23", "2020-03-05"],
        "value": [10, 20, 16, 31, 56],
    }
)
df['date']=df['date'].astype("Datetime64")
```

OR

via `pd.Timestamp()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "group": ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A"],
        "date": list(map(pd.Timestamp,["2020-01-02", "2020-01-13", "2020-02-01", "2020-02-23", "2020-03-05"])),
        "value": [10, 20, 16, 31, 56],
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it's a problem to convert date after the creation of the dataframe? You can chain the `df` creation with `astype`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"group": ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A"],
     "date": ["2020-01-02", "2020-01-13", "2020-02-01", "2020-02-23", "2020-03-05"],
     "value": [10, 20, 16, 31, 56],
    }).astype({'date': 'datetime64'})
```

```
>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------  --------------  -----
 0   group   5 non-null      object
 1   date    5 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 2   value   5 non-null      int64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 248.0+ bytes
```

Comment: When creating Minimum Viable Examples it's often beneficial (at least for me) to set everything directly in the dataframe creation and remove clutter. Didn't know I can use .astype() with a dict input, that will come in handy, thanks.

Comment: I think `astype` is much readable than apply a function inside the dataframe or a nested series.